# why kernel method is not overfitting?

Tags: regression, linear-model, kernel-trick

A question comes to my mind and confuses me:

Simply consider kernel method for regression. If kernel method is equivalently solving a **infinite dimensional linear regression problem**, then there should be equivalently **infinite amount of parameters**, why does that not necessarily lead to overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

In kernel method, we don't solve the infinite dimensional regression problem directly. Instead, we solve a dual problem where the inner product of the features are taken a.k.a the kernel trick. The matrix of the inner product has the same size as the number of data points. Hence, the number of parameters are limited to the number of data points.

Now if the matrix of the inner product is full rank, you will indeed overfit (with exact fit). Usually we apply L2 regularisation to prevent overfitting and also to allow the problem to be solvable when the matrix is not full rank.